# 64 bit pygame installation and error

Tags: macos, pygame

When I install a 64 bit python 2.7 on mac yosemite, i cant get the pygame for python 2.7 to work on it because the python 2.7 is a 64 bit version and the pygame is a 32 bit version, so what should I do

Answer (score 0):

Download the 32 bit (x86) version of python, as pygame does not support 64 bit.